# React-Native: Find the height of the Header bar

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to programmatically find the height of the Header bar (the one that shows 'Hitchhiking Map' on the following screenshot? I.e. the height from the top of the screen to the bottom of the Header bar.

A cross-platform solution would be ideal.

Edit: I'm using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) which renders the header bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `TotalNavHeight` like so:

```
import { Navigator } from 'react-native'

// ...

let height = Navigator.NavigationBar.Styles.General.TotalNavHeight
```

Comment: Neat! Thank a lot

Comment: Update: `Navigator` is deprecated as of this writing. Check here for details. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

Comment: Any current solution to get this height?